# A problem occurred configuring project ':uni_links'

Tags: flutter, gradle

I want to use uni_links package in my Flutter project but when I run it I get the following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':uni_links'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':uni_links:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
     Required by:
         project :uni_links
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.3/gradle-3.5.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
2
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':uni_links' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue check do you have `google()` repo in your project's level `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() //HAVE YOU MISS IT?
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() //HAVE YOU MISS IT?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have.  `repositories {  google()  mavenCentral()  }`